# Modifying values with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am facing a problem quite similar to the one explained in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy). This code works but raises a warning:

```
In [296]: dfb = DataFrame({'a' : ['one', 'one', 'two',
   .....:                         'three', 'two', 'one', 'six'],
   .....:                  'c' : np.arange(7)})
   .....: 
   # This will show the SettingWithCopyWarning
   # but the frame values will be set
   In [297]: dfb['c'][dfb.a.str.startswith('o')] = 42
```

Is there anyway to implement the same behaviour based in a filter without raising the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `loc`, place the boolean condition within the square brackets `[]` and the column of interest after the comma so you are not performing [chained indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy):

```
In [40]:

dfb.loc[dfb.a.str.startswith('o'),'c'] = 42
dfb
Out[40]:
       a   c
0    one  42
1    one  42
2    two   2
3  three   3
4    two   4
5    one  42
6    six   6
```